# how to make excel into dict by xlrd

Tags: python, excel

I have the following data in Excel:

```
Column(A) Column(B)   Column(C)
Header1   
A         a
          FC           Qty
select   a1            1
         a2            2
derived  a3            3
Header 2
B         b
          FC          Qty
select    b1           1
derived   b2           2
          b3           3
```

And I need to add this data to a dictionary in the following format (dict with tuples):

```
my_dict = { A:[a,select:[(a1,1),(a2,2),(a3,3)], derived:[(a3,3)]], B:[b,select:(b1,1),derived:[(b2,2),(b3,3)]]}
```

Comment: What did you try?  Try something and post the code.

Comment: i want head1 as testcase1, and i can open a, and select a1, a2, and check a3 value.